# ConstraintLayout, Elevation of Child Views, and Backward Compatibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` and one `Button` and an `ImageView` as its child views. The `ImageView` is placed over the `Button` with the expectation that the `ImageView` would be drawn over the `Button`. (Definitely, I could have added the image as a drawabl with the `Button`. But, in my scenario I want to do some animation with the button width and I want the the `ImageView` to stay as it is). However, the `ImageView` is drawn below the `Button` as the `Button` has a 2dp elevation on its default state [[Material Design Guidline]](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design). This elevation rises to 8dp when the button is pressed. Generally, we'll need to set the `elevation` or `translationZ` property of the `ImageView` to more than 2dp to make the `ImageView` appear over the button. But, the `elevation` property nor the `translationZ` property is supported before the API level 21. I am require to support API level 19. Also, elevation is not achievable using design library yet. Maintaining the conditions, is there any way to draw the `ImageView` over the `Button` inside the `ConstraintLayout`?

```
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/input_margin_bottom">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_account"
                    style="@style/RocketTheme.EditText"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_bill_pay"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_biller_id"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="12"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

                <Button
                    style="@style/RocketTheme.EditText.SideButton"
                    android:id="@+id/ib_get_contact"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:text="Select Biller"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_bill_pay"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:elevation="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_round"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout xml code.

Comment: just wrap your ImageView with FrameLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I am going with for now. According to android documentation, the later sibling is drawn later. So, in general if a `View` comes later as siblings in the layout file it will be drawn over the other siblings. However, the button has a elevation by default and so it will be drawn above the `Views` having lower elevation in API above 21.

We can set an `elevation` or `translationZ` in the sibling to make it appear above the `Button`. We also need to make sure the `View` we want on the top is placed later in the layout. In API below 21, the elevation won't work and the later `View` is drawn on top.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap your button with a FrameLayout. It will allow you to pile a view on top of the one below. See the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xml cut imageview's code and paste it below button's code. elevation is not supported on older devices

Comment: I looked into the documentation and according to it, the later sibling is drawn later. So, in general if a view comes later as siblings in the layout file it will be drawn over the other siblings. However, the button has a elevation by default and so it will be drawn above the views having lower elevation in API above 21. So, putting the ImageView below doesn't works.